# FederatedPassiveSignInStatus control is not redirecting to STS correctly. Please Help

Tags: single-sign-on, sts-securitytokenservice, wif

I'm using the:

```
<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" namespace="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.Controls" tagprefix="wif" %>
<wif:FederatedPassiveSignInStatus runat="server" ID="SignInStatus1" SignOutAction="FederatedPassiveSignOut" SignOutPageUrl="Default.aspx" />
```

When the user signs in the control displays a link "Log out".  When they click the link, it redirects them to:

```
https://dev.apps.ahca.myflorida.com/SingleSignOnPortal/?wa=wsignout1.0&wreply=https://dev.apps.ahca.myflorida.com/ClaimsEnableWebSiteEx01/Default.aspx&wa=wsignout1.0&wreply=https://dev.apps.ahca.myflorida.com/ClaimsEnableWebSiteEx01/Default.aspx
```

This causes unexpected behaviors with my STS provider and is not what I would like to happen.  I'm thinking I have something configured wrong for this to happen.  So, Instead of click the FederatedPassiveSignInStatus control... If I just paste this url into my browser:

```
https://dev.apps.ahca.myflorida.com/SingleSignOnPortal/Default.aspx?wa=wsignout1.0&wreply=https://dev.apps.ahca.myflorida.com/ClaimsEnableWebSiteEx01/Default.aspx
```

Then everything works fine!

So, my question is.. how can I get this darn control to work correctly?  I cant find any documentation on the internet/Programming WIF book/Identity training Kit (april release) about this control or how to use it properly.

Way to go microsoft.

Please help this frustrated programmer.

Thanks

Comment: Still have not got a good answer.  I have just created a hyperlink with the proper signout url.. but I would like to get it so the ASP.NET Identity user control can work properly as apposed to just hardcoding a hyperlink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one of our samples (sample #1 from here: http://claimsid.codeplex.com) we are doing exactly the same.

Our control looks like this:

```
 <idfx:FederatedPassiveSignInStatus ID="FederatedPassiveSignInStatus" runat="server" 
                        OnSignedOut="OnFederatedPassiveSignInStatusSignedOut" SignOutText="Logout" FederatedPassiveSignOut="true" SignOutAction="FederatedPassiveSignOut" />
```

Might be you are missing a FederatedPassiveSignOut="true" ?

Comment: I added that property to the control even though I didnt have any intellisense for it and nothing has changed.  Also, I have another problem when they click that link to sign in..and they authenticate with the STS provider.  They then get redirected back to the relying party, but with login.aspx appeneded to the address and then I get the Page not found error message.  Why does it append login.aspx? I cant find anywhere why this behavior would happen.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry, the URL I supplied was incorrect. Try downloading one of them and see if it runs ok.